# How to use cast function to add dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a function to represent when an employees (agents) 6 month review will take place, using date arithmetic by adding on 6 months to their hire date and I can't seem to get it right. I can't use the date add/set function for this.

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, 
  EmpLastName,
  CAST(DateHired, + 6 MONTH) AS ReviewDate
From Employees
```

Comment: *I can't use the date add/set function for this.* why not?

Comment: what is DateHired data type?

Comment: Dateadd is new since 2008 so maybe OP is working in 2005 or prior.

Comment: @JacobH DATEADD was NOT new in 2008. That function has been around since at least sql server 6.5 when I started working with it...and it wasn't new then that I know of. The MS documentation on these things is kind of sketchy because it will say things like "starting with 2008" which is rubbish. They changed the documentation because they don't want official documentation for version no longer being supported.

Comment: Fair enough. If there are arbitrary requirements that don't make sense, it must be a homework assignment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add 180 days.

```
select dateHired + 180  reviewDate
from etc
```

Comment: Good answer because it is simple, easy and consistent. No aggregation is necessary.

Comment: Would be much better to use DATEADD and avoid the shorthand. This will fail if dateHired is a date or datetime2. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Attention, adding 180 days does not mean exactly 6 months!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, 
  EmpLastName,
  DATEADD(MONTH, 6,CAST(DateHired AS DATE)) AS ReviewDate
From Employees
```